# Is there no modularize option for Kotlin files in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am currently trying to modularize my codebase and utilised the modularize option that appears in the refactor menu for a particular Java class. This works pretty well.
However , i have now moved to the Kotlin section of the codebase and it seems the modularize option does not exist when i click on refactor for a Kotlin class. Am i missing something or is this feature unavailable at this point?

Comment: Hello, could you please attach the image of refactor menu for java class? :)

Comment: @Dishonered Just bumped into this. Did you found a solution? Tested with a java class and it worked but unfortunately, it does not work for kt files

Comment: I have not found anything yet. Upcoming version may include support though.